# Java JDK7 on Mac OS X 10.7.3

Tags: java

I've to use OpenJML and that requires Java JDK7. I've installed JDK7 so far following the instructions from this link: http://formalmethods.insttech.washington.edu/software/openjml.html

After the installation my Eclipse project didn't show any errors any more because it found JavaSE7 now.

But when I type `java -version` in Terminal there is still ...

```
java version "1.6.0_29"
```

... displayed there. What can I do to use 1.7 in the shell as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new JDK will be installed into:

`/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines`

On my Mac with the developer preview installed you can run:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/JDK\ 1.7.0\ Developer\ Preview.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -version

java version "1.7.0_04-ea"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_04-ea-b225)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.0-b09, mixed mode)
```

You can select the current system JVM via the Java Preferences application (use spotlight to find it).

Alternatively you can use `/usr/libexec/java_home --version 1.7` to find the correct `JAVA_HOME` value for the requested JDK.

Answer (score 0):

eclipse uses the java that is configured in your environmental variables.

not sure how to get there in mac but you should enter these values

Uservariables (create or edit existing):

Variable | Value

`JAVA_HOME` | `Pathto\Java\jdk1.7.0_03`

Systemvariables(edit+ add, dont delete previous entries!):

`Path` | `Pathto\Java\jdk1.7.0_03\bin`

Answer (score 0):

First, please uninstall JDK1.6
Need root permisstion:


*cd /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines


rm -rf 1.6.0.jdk/*

Second, download from oracle website http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u65-b17/jdk-7u65-macosx-x64.dmg

Third, extract dmg, double click install icon, press 'next' until finish.